# Adding String to List MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Im using MVC4 Razor and I just want to ask how to create a List of string and use it in a field seperated by comma? Cause I tried something and it shows an error `Cannon implicitly convert type void to object` Ill show you my set of codes

declared this on my header:

```
 List<string> elements = new List<string>();
```

Then I want this `List<string> elements` to get populated inside a foreach loop

```
    <tbody>
            @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Cards.Count; ++i)
                 {
                    var counter = i + 1;
                    <tr>    
                        <td valign="middle"> 
                            <p class="small">@counter</p>
                        </td>
                        <td valign="middle">                         
                             <p class="small">@Model.Cards[i].Number.Substring(0,5)</p>
                        </td>
                        @elements.Add(Model.Cards[i].Number.Substring(0,5))
                   </tr>
                 }
    </tbody>
```

And use it in a Label

```
<div> Card Number <p> @String.Join(", ", elements.ToArray()) </p></div>
```

Comment: That code belongs in the controller, not the view (and you pass a view model that includes a `string` property for the result you want to use in the label)

Comment: @StephenMuecke so sir what can you suggest that i will be using in the view

Comment: @StephenMuecke Im stucked at this code statement for 3 hrs already

Comment: The code in your view will simply be `@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Cards.Count; ++i) { .... <p>@Model.Cards[i].Number</p> }` because the the value of `Number` will be only the 5 characters you want. And you would use `Card Number <p>Model.CardNumber</p>` where `CardNumber` is the joined result (again calculated in the controller, not the view)

Answer (score 0):

If you flow **@Stephen Muecke**, suggestion it's best. But if you flow your process the your code look like:

```
@{
    List<string> elements = new List<string>();
 }

     <tbody>
            @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Cards.Count; ++i)
                 {
                    var counter = i + 1;
                    var cardNumber=Model.Cards[i].Number.Substring(0,5);
                    elements.Add(cardNumber);
                    <tr>    
                        <td valign="middle"> 
                            <p class="small">@counter</p>
                        </td>
                        <td valign="middle">                         
                             <p class="small">@cardNumber</p>
                        </td>                    
                   </tr>

                 }
    </tbody>
@{
    var str=string.Join(", ", elements.ToArray());
}

<div> Card Number <p> @str </p></div>
```